# Calling A Sub in VBA with multiple arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I want to call sub with multiple argument but I got an error **Syntax error**

I tried it on Ms Excel 2013

```
Sub Withdrawal(Query As String, Savelocation As String)

    'Query Data
    Dim ReturnArray
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
    DBPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\Data.xlsx"
    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
    Conn.Open sconnect
    mrs.Open Query, Conn
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Savelocation).Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    mrs.Close
    Conn.Close
End Sub

Sub CashWithdrawal()
    Dim CashWFYC As String
    Dim Location As String
    Location = "CashWithdrawal"
    CashWFYC = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [TT$]"
    sSQLSting = CashWFYC 
    Withdrawal(sSQLSting, Location)
End Sub
```

I expect the output that got from that `sSQLSting` query should be save in `Location`

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: Remove the brackets: `Withdrawal sSQLSting, Location` (FYI, this has come up many, many times before)

Comment: @Rory Thanks. Just found a dup for closure. I shouldn't have been so lazy.

Comment: Your actual code was `Withdrawal (sSQLSting, Location)`, not `Withdrawal(sSQLSting, Location)`. That space is the VBE telling you "this isn't an argument list, it's an expression I'm going to try to evaluate and pass `ByVal` as the first argument to the `Withdrawal` procedure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call without parentheses. Within parentheses is for function calls.

```
Withdrawal sSQLSting, Location
```

Please put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code and declare all your variables including with explicit type.

Comment: By remove parantheses I got another error ```ByRef argument type mismatch```

Comment: Declare sSQLSting as string  It means your receiving sub wants two strings so check both arguments being passed are strings. And put Option Explicit at the top of your sub.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I found it I forgot it

Comment: you are welcome. Sorry for closing the question abruptly on you. I should have done that immediately but wasn't really thinking.